# How do you programmatically update query params in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I can't seem to find how to update query params with react-router without using `<Link/>`. `hashHistory.push(url)` doesn't seem to register query params, and it doesn't seem like you can pass a query object or anything as a second argument.

How do you change the url from `/shop/Clothes/dresses` to `/shop/Clothes/dresses?color=blue` in react-router without using `<Link>`?

And is an `onChange` function really the only way to listen for query changes? Why aren't query changes automatically detected and reacted-to the way that param changes are?

Comment: you should be using the history singleton as referred to in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Within the `push` method of `hashHistory`, you can specify your query parameters. For instance,

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/dresses',
  search: '?color=blue'
})
```

or

```
history.push('/dresses?color=blue')
```

You can check out this [repository](https://github.com/mjackson/history) for additional examples on using `history`

Comment: awesome! Is there anyway to pass a query object {color: blue, size: 10} instead of a string?

Comment: @claireablani Currently, I don't think that is supported

Comment: okay - do you know if it is customary to just stringify the query object then before calling hashHistory push?

Comment: @claireablani you could try this `router.push({
        pathname: '/path',
        state: { color: 'blue', size: 10 },
      });`

Comment: Just for clarification, this no longer works in react router v4. For that, see @kristupas-repečka's answer

Comment: @dkniffin - his answer is also deprecated :)

Comment: unstable times we live in.

Comment: I tried this and got `history.push is not a function` as a response

Comment: In router v6, the useNavigate hook is the current technique: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate

Comment: Works like charm.

Answer (score 61):

You can use the **replace** functionality instead of **pushing** a new route on every change

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router';

const MyComponent = ()=>{
   const history = useHistory();
   const location = useLocation();

   const onChange=(event)=>{
     const {name, value} = event?.target;
     const params = new URLSearchParams({[name]: value });
     history.replace({ pathname: location.pathname, search: params.toString() });       
   }

   return <input name="search" onChange={onChange} />
}
```

This preserves the history instead of pushing a new path on every change

**Update** - February 2022 (V6)

As pointed out by Matrix Spielt useHistory was replaced by useNavigate to make the changes. There is also a convenient method for this called useSearchParams I only got to [read the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) and have not run this but this should work

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
// import from react-router should also work but following docs
// import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router';

const MyComponent = ()=>{
   const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

   const onChange=(event)=>{
     const {name, value} = event?.target;
     setSearchParams({[name]: value})       
   }

   return <input name="search" onChange={onChange} />
}
```

Comment: Can only the `search` be replaced without the `pathname`? (assuming `pathname` will be used)

Comment: useHistory() was by replaced useNavigate() in version 6

Comment: Thx! Here's the link to the web version of [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) docs. @craques

Comment: @Craques Thanks for posting both old and new versions of this logic - the rabbit hole I almost fell into trying to upgrade to 6.x was a big, fat, hard no!

Comment: How do you do this outside a component?

Answer (score 54):

[John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40161954/2115494) is correct. When I'm dealing with params I also need `URLSearchParams` interface:

```
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/client',
    search: "?" + new URLSearchParams({clientId: clientId}).toString()
})
```

You might also need to wrap your component with a `withRouter` HOC eg. `export default withRouter(YourComponent);`.

Comment: No need to use `.toString()` here because prepending the question mark will coerce it automatically.

Answer (score 51):

Example using react-router v4, redux-thunk and react-router-redux(5.0.0-alpha.6) package.

When user uses search feature, I want him to be able to send url link for same query to a colleague.

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import qs from 'query-string';

export const search = () => (dispatch) => {
    const query = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' };

    //API call to retrieve records
    //...

    const searchString = qs.stringify(query);

    dispatch(push({
        search: searchString
    }))
}
```

Comment: `react-router-redux` is deprecated

Comment: I think this must now be done by rendering the `<Redirect>` tag, link to  [docs page](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect)

Comment: You can just wrap your component in `withReducer` HOC which will give you the `history` prop. And then you can run `history.push({ search: querystring }`.

Comment: Instead of `react-router-redux`, you can use `connected-react-router` which is not deprecated.

Answer (score 17):

For React Router `v6+` just use the new [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook (specifically `setSearchParams`):

```js
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams()

setSearchParams(`?${new URLSearchParams({ paramName: 'whatever' })}`)
```

For React Router `v5` use [useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory):

```js
const history = useHistory()

history.push({
    pathname: '/the-path',
    search: `?${new URLSearchParams({ paramName: 'whatever' })}`
})
```

**Note:** [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) is just an optional (recommended!) convenience helper here, but you can also use just a raw string with url parameters.

Comment: So about your *note* and the V6 way: we do can use `setSearchParams({ paramName: 'whatever' })` -> that will be just as fine?

Answer (score 15):

for react-router v4.3

```js
const addQuery = (key, value) => {
  let pathname = props.location.pathname;
  // returns path: '/app/books'
  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
  // returns the existing query string: '?type=fiction&author=fahid'
  searchParams.set(key, value);
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: pathname,
    search: searchParams.toString()
  });
};

const removeQuery = (key) => {
  let pathname = props.location.pathname;
  // returns path: '/app/books'
  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
  // returns the existing query string: '?type=fiction&author=fahid'
  searchParams.delete(key);
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: pathname,
    search: searchParams.toString()
  });
};
```

```js
function SomeComponent({ location }) {
  return <div>
    <button onClick={ () => addQuery('book', 'react')}>search react books</button>
    <button onClick={ () => removeQuery('book')}>remove search</button>
  </div>;
}
```

To know more on URLSearchParams from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```js
var paramsString = "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api";
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

//Iterate the search parameters.
for (let p of searchParams) {
  console.log(p);
}

searchParams.has("topic") === true; // true
searchParams.get("topic") === "api"; // true
searchParams.getAll("topic"); // ["api"]
searchParams.get("foo") === null; // true
searchParams.append("topic", "webdev");
searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api&topic=webdev"
searchParams.set("topic", "More webdev");
searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=More+webdev"
searchParams.delete("topic");
searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams"
```

Answer (score 11):

With React Router V6 we can achieve it like this

```
import { useNavigate, createSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

/* In React Component */
const navigate = useNavigate();
const params = {
  color: 'blue',
};
const options = {
  pathname: '/shop/Clothes/dresses',
  search: `?${createSearchParams(params)}`,
};
navigate(options, { replace: true });
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough documentation! Knowing that options contains both `pathname` and `search` helped me figure out how I was going to translate the following `history.push({ search: urlSearchParams.toString(), state })` into navigate. I ended up doing `naviate({ search: urlSearchParams.toString()}, { state })`. What I learned is that while previously the `state` property lived in the first parameter of `history.push`, it is part of the second parameter in `navigate`.

Comment: Included here is the type definition of the navigate function. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

Comment: Also if you only want to update the (query params) search portion of url, then try https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params

Answer (score 9):

You can use hook `useHistory`
Make sure that you're using `function` based component
Import this at the top

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom"
```

In your component,

```
const history = useHistory()
history.push({
    pathname: window.location.pathname,
    search: '?color=blue'
})
```

Answer (score 7):

react-router-dom **v5** solution

```js
  import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'; 
  const history = useHistory(); // useHistory hook inside functional component  
    
  history.replace({search: (new URLSearchParams({activetab : 1})).toString()});
```

it is recommended to use URLSearchParams as it can take care of  spaces and special chars in query params while encoding and decoding the query params

```js
    new URLSearchParams({'active tab':1 }).toString() // 'active+tab=1'
    new URLSearchParams('active+tab=1').get('active tab') // 1
```

Answer (score 4):

From [DimitriDushkin on GitHub](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1100#issuecomment-272800685):

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

/**
 * @param {Object} query
 */
export const addQuery = (query) => {
  const location = Object.assign({}, browserHistory.getCurrentLocation());

  Object.assign(location.query, query);
  // or simple replace location.query if you want to completely change params

  browserHistory.push(location);
};

/**
 * @param {...String} queryNames
 */
export const removeQuery = (...queryNames) => {
  const location = Object.assign({}, browserHistory.getCurrentLocation());
  queryNames.forEach(q => delete location.query[q]);
  browserHistory.push(location);
};
```

or

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { addQuery, removeQuery } from '../../utils/utils-router';

function SomeComponent({ location }) {
  return <div style={{ backgroundColor: location.query.paintRed ? '#f00' : '#fff' }}>
    <button onClick={ () => addQuery({ paintRed: 1 })}>Paint red</button>
    <button onClick={ () => removeQuery('paintRed')}>Paint white</button>
  </div>;
}

export default withRouter(SomeComponent);
```

Comment: this is for react-router v3 and will not work with subsequent versions

Answer (score 3):

Using [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) module is the recommended one when you need a module to parse your query string in ease.

> http://localhost:3000?token=xxx-xxx-xxx

```
componentWillMount() {
    var query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    if (query.token) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("jwt", query.token);
        store.dispatch(push("/"));
    }
}
```

Here, I am redirecting back to my client from Node.js server after successful Google-Passport authentication, which is redirecting back with token as query param.

I am parsing it with query-string module, saving it and updating the query params in the url with push from [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux).

Answer (score 2):

It can also be written this way

```
this.props.history.push(`${window.location.pathname}&page=${pageNumber}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @Craques explained we can use the replace functionality instead of pushing a new route on every change. However, **in version 6 of react-router, useHistory() was by replaced useNavigate()**, which returns only a function. You can pass options to the function, to achieve the same effect as the **old** location.replace():

```js
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const to = { pathname: location.pathname, search: newParams.toString() };
navigate(to, { replace: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer you to use below function that is `ES6` style:

```
getQueryStringParams = query => {
    return query
        ? (/^[?#]/.test(query) ? query.slice(1) : query)
            .split('&')
            .reduce((params, param) => {
                    let [key, value] = param.split('=');
                    params[key] = value ? decodeURIComponent(value.replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : '';
                    return params;
                }, {}
            )
        : {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case typing into input field outputs it into browser's url as a query string, using React JS functional component as shown below

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const Search = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
  const history = useHistory()

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setQuery(e.target.value)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams()
    if (query) {
      params.append('name', query)
    } else {
      params.delete('name')
    }
    history.push({ search: params.toString() })
  }, [query, history])

  return <input type="text" value={query} onChange={onChange} />
}

export default Search
```

browser's URL Query

`/search?name=query_here`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've come up with for `react-router-dom@v6`

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

const handleNavigate = () => {
  navigate({
    pathname: 'TARGET_PATH', // Path to navigate
    search: new URLSearchParams({
      key1: value1, // Query string
      key2: value2, // Another query string
    }).toString(),
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For react-router-dom v6:

```js
const [currentQueryParameters, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
setSearchParams({ paramName: 'paramValue' });
```

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently on `react-router` v5 in a running project and cannot easily migrate to v6.
I wrote a hook that allows to read and modify a single URL param while leaving the other URL params untouched.
Arrays are treated as lists of comma separated values:
`?products=pipe,deerstalker,magnifying_glass`

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

const getDecodedUrlParam = (name: string, locationSearch: string, _default?: any) => {
  const params = deserialize(locationSearch);
  const param = params[name];

  if (_default && Array.isArray(_default)) {
    return param
      ? param.split(',').map((v: string) => decodeURIComponent(v))
      : _default;
  }

  return param ? decodeURIComponent(param) : _default;
};

const deserialize = (locationSearch: string): any => {
  if (locationSearch.startsWith('?')) {
    locationSearch = locationSearch.substring(1);
  }
  const parts = locationSearch.split('&');
  return Object.fromEntries(parts.map((part) => part.split('=')));
};

const serialize = (params: any) =>
  Object.entries(params)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
    .join('&');

export const useURLSearchParam = (name: string, _default?: any) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const value: any = getDecodedUrlParam(name, location.search, _default);
  const _update = useCallback(
    (value: any) => {
      const params = deserialize(location.search);
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        params[name] = value.map((v) => encodeURIComponent(v)).join(',');
      } else {
        params[name] = encodeURIComponent(value);
      }
      history.replace({ pathname: location.pathname, search: serialize(params) });
    },
    [history, name]
  );
  const _delete = useCallback(() => {
    const params = deserialize(location.search);
    delete params[name];
    history.replace({ pathname: location.pathname, search: serialize(params) });
  }, [history, name]);
  return [value, _update, _delete];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a **simple hook** to ease up the job.

Lets imagine your url is something like this:
`/search?origin=home&page=1`

```
function useUrl(param: string) {

    const history = useHistory()
    const { search, pathname } = useLocation()
    const url = new URLSearchParams(search)

    const urlParam = url.get(param)
    const [value, setValue] = useState(urlParam !== null ? urlParam : '')

    function _setValue(val: string){
        url.set(param, val)
        history.replace({ pathname, search: url.toString() }); 
        setValue(val)
    }

    return [value, _setValue]
}
```

Then the actual usage:

```
function SearchPage() {

    const [origin] = useUrl("origin")
    const [page, setPage] = useUrl("page")

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Return to: {origin}</p>
            <p>Current Page: {page}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// react-router-dom v6

// import
import { useNavigate, createSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

// useSearchParams hook
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

// usage
const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
params.id = '123';
params.color = 'white';

// set new parameters
setSearchParams(params);
```

***!!! BE AWARE !!!*** This will only update the query parameters on the current page, but you will not be able to navigate back (browser back btn) to a previous route because this option does not change your history. To have in place this behavior check a previous answer:  [https://stackoverflow.com/users/6160270/rakesh-sharma 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73206229/7745982)

Answer (score 0):

like @kuza grave did

to catch the params in version 5

eg lets say your url looks like Mylink?name=johndoe&tenant=code

```
import { useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

const { search } = useLocation()
const url = new URLSearchParams(search);


let [name,setName] = useState(null);
let [tenant,setTenant] = useState(null);


useEffect(()=>{
  
 setName(url.get('name'));
 setTenant(url.get('tenant'));

 console.log(name,tenant);
},[url,name,tenant]);



// you can use it in your page

Return (
<div>{name}</div>
<div>{tenant}</div>
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).