# React-router-dom push

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So i'm learning react js thru an ebook and stuck on it,

I keep getting error: "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.."

my App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import IssueList from './IssueList.jsx';
import IssueEdit from './IssueEdit.jsx';

const contentNode = document.getElementById('contents');
const NoMatch = () =><p>Page Not Found</p>;

const RoutedApp = () => (
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={ () => <Redirect to="/issues" /> } />
        <Route exact path="/issues" component={withRouter(IssueList)} />
        <Route path="/issues/:id" component={IssueEdit} />
        <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(<RoutedApp />, contentNode);

if(module.hot){
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

IssueList.jsx

```
...
import React from 'react';
import QueryString from 'query-string';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...
export default class IssueList extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = { issues: [] };
       this.createIssue = this.createIssue.bind(this);
       this.setFilter = this.setFilter.bind(this);
   }

   setFilter(query){
       this.props.router.push({ pathname: this.props.location.pathname, query });
   }
}
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it leads me to another error: "Hash history cannot PUSH the same path..", if I use BrowserRouter it doesn't fire any event nor error in console :/

Comment: Instead of push use replace if you intend to change the URL query paramters

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri how to achieve it? I changed it to this.props.history.replace({ ... }) but nothing happened :/

Comment: do you mean the query parameters did not change or they changed and you screen did not take any effect

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes the params doesn't change and browser doesn't navigate to the given query string. does it has anything to do with "Hash history cannot PUSH the same path.."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work finally, thanks to this post:
[How do you programmatically update query params in react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161516/how-do-you-programmatically-update-query-params-in-react-router)

```
...
import React from 'react';
import QueryString from 'query-string';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...
export default class IssueList extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = { issues: [] };
       this.createIssue = this.createIssue.bind(this);
       this.setFilter = this.setFilter.bind(this);
   }

   setFilter(query){
       this.props.history.push({ 
           pathname: this.props.location.pathname, 
           search: '?' + QueryString.stringify(query) 
       });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your component up in react-router to have access to history property.
So your `IssueList.jsx` should look like this:

```
...
import React from 'react';
import QueryString from 'query-string';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...
class IssueList extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = { issues: [] };
       this.createIssue = this.createIssue.bind(this);
       this.setFilter = this.setFilter.bind(this);
   }

   setFilter(query){
       this.props.history.push({ pathname: this.props.location.pathname, query });
   }
}

export default withRouter(IssueList)
```

Comment: this leads me to another error: "Hash history cannot PUSH the same path.." :/