# Programmatically set params in React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React Router 4 I can define

```
<Route path="/calendar/:view/:year?/:month?/:day?" component={Calendar} />
```

to pass props from a URL to my Calendar component.

Inside the Calendar component, I want to programmatically set the URL params. The docs show how to do this using `history.push()`, but this requires you to format the URL yourself like ``` history.push(``${view}/${year}/${month}/${day}``) ```. But I want to update the URL without being coupled to the route structure, ideally something like `history.push({ view: 'month', year: '2018' })`.

Is this possible? It seems odd to me that React Router helps split up the URL into params, but doesn't provide a nice mechanism to set those params?

Comment: Directly with react router **No** you can [check this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161516/how-do-you-programmatically-update-query-params-in-react-router/40161954) but if you find yourself writing this a lot you can always write an Utils function to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement this using the `path-to-regexp` package that React Router uses:

```
this.props.history.push(pathToRegexp.compile(this.props.match.path)({ view: 'month', year: '2018' ));
```

Comment: Mind linking what package is ```pathToRegexp```?

Comment: Currently doesn't work too well. If I pass ```view``` and ```month```, without a ```year```, it renders ```month``` in place of ```year```, like ```/calendar/view/month``` instead of ```/calendar/view/x/month```

Comment: In the end I switched to router5 :)

Comment: @dhulme how does v5 handle this?

Comment: @Rohmer I now use my own wrapper around react-router https://github.com/dhulme/react-router-extensions/blob/master/src/routing.ts

Answer (score 8):

I do that by using match.path and generatePath. Here is an example:

```
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: generatePath(this.props.match.path, {orderId: "latest", orderItemId: "latest"})
});
```

You can read about it here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/generatePath and here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/match.

Thats the cleanest solution I found so far for preventing the route component from knowing to much about where it will be allocated later in the path structure. 
Maybe it fits your (or someone else's) need.

Comment: I can confirm this working. Keep in mind that `generatePath` will encode special characters like `/`, so you might want to use `decodeURIComponent` if you, like me, do a catch-all of all path params that are passed.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that instead of `history.push()` as answered, you would use `history.replace()`.

with `replace` you would not affect the history in case the user would want to navigate backward in the browser.

```js
this.props.history.replace({
    pathname: generatePath(this.props.match.path, {orderId: "latest", orderItemId: "latest"})
});
```

Comment: I think it's better to use push, because user's generally expect to use the back button to navigate back through the app

Comment: I agree but in this case there is only params replacement in the current page, and not navigation between pages in the app

Comment: This should be a comment on Mario's answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if what you want is achievable, because if you pass the params to the react-router-dom, the params goes to the URL, but if you decouple the params with the URL structure, how will react-router know how to change the URL? The same URL may match multiple routes, with multiple params structures (and nested routes).

Comment: I meant that when the URL params come in as props into a component, they are decoupled from the URL structure as they are just an object. But when you update the URL, you can't pass in an object, you have to form the URL manually.

Comment: This is not an answer.