# How to pass parameters to URL in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a URL contains a few parameters, for example, `myURL?pageNo={pNo}&search1={campus}&search2={s2}`. `search` and `search2` are two dropdown boxes. How to update the `search1` and `search2` values in `handleChange()`?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
//import Course from './components/Course.js';
const API_URL='myURL';
class App extends Component {
state = {
query: '',
campus:'',
results: [],
TotalRecordCount:0,
currentPage:1
}
 //URL with parameters
getInfo = () => {
  let query='pageNo=${currentPage}&campus=${campus}';
  axios.get(`${API_URL}?${this.state.query}`)
    .then(response => {
     // console.log(response);
      this.setState({
        results: response.data,

      });
    });
}
//event handler
handleChange(event){
 this.setState({
  campus: event.target.value}, <!--?? how to replace campus value in query?
 () => {    
        this.getInfo()
  }
)
}
```

//render

```
render() {
    const results=this.state.results;
    return (
    <div className="App">
     <form>
     <div className="campusFilter">
       <select name="campus" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
         <option value="">Select a Campus</option>

        <option>Campus A</option>
        <option>Campus B</option>
       </select>
       </div>
    <p>{this.state.query}</p>
    <!--display results here-->
  </form>
  </div>
  )
 }
 }
export default App;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn’t clear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161516/how-do-you-programmatically-update-query-params-in-react-router - it's probably the same

Comment: Yes, it is similar to that. how to update the parameter value in the URL. Is it possible not to use router? Thanks.